# Unit of $area in the field calculator in Albers Equal Area projection (ESRI: 102033)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I need to find the area of a set of polygons that are spread across South America. I researched a bit, and found that the Albers Equal Area projections reduces distortion and can be used for calculating areas within large landmasses.

My question is: What unit is the output of the $area function in the field calculator when using the ESRI: 102033 projection?

Comment: `$area` uses the square of the unit of measurement of the CRS the layer is in. With some CRS QGIS produces weird values, in this case you may use `area($geometry)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS, when you set the CRS, there is a window t the bottom that shows the **WKT** version of the CRS, and the **Proj** version. It contains the length unit. The area is the square of that.

For South America Albers Equal Area Conic (ESRI 102033), for example, it is:

```
WKT
PROJCRS["South_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",
    BASEGEOGCRS["SAD69",
        DATUM["South American Datum 1969",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1967 Modified",6378160,298.25,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["South_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",-32,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-60,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",-5,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",-42,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["South America"],
        BBOX[-60,-90,15,-30]],
    ID["ESRI",102033]]
```

The **Proj** version has the units of length (so does the WKT, but the proj is quicker to read.)

```
Proj4
+proj=aea +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs
Extent
-90.00, -60.00, -30.00, 15.00
```

So the length units are metres. Therefore area units will be square metres.

Comment: Or simply look up the units in the layer properties / Information tab: there you have a line saying: `units: meters`

Comment: You have a point there! Still, it's good to explore the interface. I'll be using your way from now on. Ironically, if it had been a command line question, I would have said 'ogrinfo!'